# Docker-Compose windows 7 compatibility

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is docker-compose compatible/stable with windows 7 ? I have been trying to use docker for local development. But I am facing volume mounting issues with docker-compose in windows 7.

Appreciate any thoughts/suggestions. Thanks.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not run on Windows natively on Windows, instead, it uses a linux-based VM that is the one that actually runs the containers, etc.

You should be able to open virtualbox and see the VM running.

The problem might be related to you using windows routes and docker being unable to find them.

It should help to diagnose the issue if you provided us with what are you trying to run and what errors docker is outputting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have faced the issue that I facing as a separate post => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018676/docker-compose-on-windows-7-could-not-locate-gemfile-or-bundle-directory