# Docker Compose on Windows 7: Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I get the following error when I run the command `docker-compose up`

> Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
> exited with code 10

Following is the code.

Note : I have added the parent directory of my code as a permanent shared folder to the VM using Oracle VM virtual box manager.

Any thoughts to resolve the issue.?

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3.0
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://proxy.com:8080
ENV HTTPS_PROXY http://proxy.com:8080
RUN mkdir /student-api
WORKDIR /student-api
ADD Gemfile /student-api/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /student-api/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /student-api
```

#### Docker Compose

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/student-api
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

Comment: Where is "." on Windows? Change that volume mount of student-api to an full path of the Docker host directory location, e.g. `/c/Users/joe/dockerproj`

Answer (score 4):

You are creating the `.bundle` directory in the container, then masking it with the host directory , because you're using a volume:

```
volumes:
    - .:/student-api
```

You need to either run the `bundle install` on the host, or remove the volume from the Compose file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

I am creating bundle directory in the container so that I can cache the gems and save time while running it.

I am using volume, because I am planning to use docker for local development. This saves me from building the image every time while making a change. 

Please correct If my approach is wrong.

Comment: I think your approach is correct, it just forces you to run it on the host when you're doing development.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mounting HOST directory within your HOME path (e.g. c:/Users/john/*).

Be advised that doing this outside HOME path does not work correctly.